# Are there any commands besides NSolve for solving equations which involve product logarithm?

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

I have two complicated equations and `NSolve` cannot give the complete set of solutions:

```
NSolve[{-0.006`  d - 0.005999999999999999`  d  ProductLog[-90.53333333333333` E^(-72.73766666666666` + 90.53333333333333` d)] == 0, 

(1 - 0.0026/T) (0.0885 (1 - T) (0.8265^(14.9832))/(d^(14.9832) + 0.8265^(14.9832)) - 
  0.978 (d^(14.9832))/(d^(14.9832) + 0.8265^(14.9832))) == 0}, {d, T}]
```

(If I round up the numbers, `NSolve` is not able to solve it.) For the above, it returns:

```
{{d -> 0.742621, T -> 0.0026}, {d -> 0.742621, T -> -1.22352}}
```

There should be at least two other solutions. For example, a simple inspection of the equations shows that $d \to 0, T \to 1$ should also be a solution. Are there any commands besides `NSolve` for solving this system?

Comment: What do you mean by "if I round up the number"? Can you please show your code? Also, `NSolve[Rationalize[eqs, 0], {d, T}, Reals]` returns `{{d -> 0, T -> 0.0026}, {d -> 0, T -> 1.}}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first equation only depends on d. Therefore, we solve it first (We need to rationalize to prevent numerical problems):

```
{eq1, eq2} = {-0.006`   d - 0.005999999999999999`   d   ProductLog[-90.53333333333333`  \
E^(-72.73766666666666` + 90.53333333333333`  d)] == 
    0, (1 - 0.0026/T)  (0.0885  (1 - T)  (0.8265^(14.9832))/(d^(14.9832) + 0.8265^(14.9832)) - 
       0.978  (d^(14.9832))/(d^(14.9832) + 0.8265^(14.9832))) == 0};
Reduce[Rationalize@eq1, d]
```

[image]

Note the integer `c[1]`. Therefore, we have an infinite number of solutions. Let us start with the simplest one d=0; We can insert this in the second equation and solve it :

```
Reduce[eq2 /. d -> 0, T]

T == 0.0026 || T == 1.
```

Now for the more complex cases. We first set `C[1]=0`:

```
d1 = 218213/
   271600 + (
    15  (-1 + 2  I  \[Pi]  C[1] - Log[2] + Log[3] + Log[5] - Log[7] - 
       Log[97]))/1358 ;

Reduce[eq2 /. d -> d1 /. C[1] -> 0 , T]
    
T == -1.22352 || T == 0.0026
```

Or e.g. for  `C[1]=1`:

```
Reduce[eq2 /. d -> d1 /. C[1] -> 1 , T]

T == 0.0026 - 1.37529*10^-19 I || T == 0.587761 - 2.33712 I
```

Note, this are complex solutions.

The general solution as a function of `c[1]` is a lengthy expression that I do not print here:

```
Reduce[eq2 /. d -> d1 , T]
```

Comment: I do not see what you mean. Where do I repeat d1 twice?

Comment: -1. `Reduce[Rationalize[eq1, 0], d]` performs `d == 0` only.

Comment: `({-0.006   d - 
      0.005999999999999999   d   ProductLog[-90.53333333333333  \
E^(-72.73766666666666 + 90.53333333333333  d)] == 
     0, (1 - 0.0026/
         T)  (0.0885  (1 -   T)  (0.8265^(14.9832))/(d^(14.9832) + 0.8265^(14.9832)) -    0.978  (d^(14.9832))/(d^(14.9832) + 0.8265^(14.9832))) == 
     0} /. {d -> 
     218213/271600 + (15   (-1 + 2   I   \[Pi]   C[1] - Log[2] +   Log[3] + Log[5] - Log[7] - Log[97]))/1358  218213/
  271600 + (15   (-1 + 2   I   \[Pi]   C[1] - Log[2] + Log[3] +    Log[5] - Log[7] - Log[97]))/1358, T -> 1.91022 - 0.459196  I}) /.  C[1] -> 1`

Comment: results in `{False,False}`.

Comment: I wonder the acceptance of  a wrong answer.

Comment: You are right, copy paste error. I corrected it

Answer (score 2):

```
FindInstance[Rationalize[{-0.006   d - 
 0.005999999999999999   d   ProductLog[-90.53333333333333  
E^(-72.73766666666666 + 90.53333333333333  d)] == 
0, (1 - 0.0026/T)  (0.0885  (1 -T)  (0.8265^(14.9832))/(d^(14.9832) + 0.8265^(14.9832)) - 
0.978  (d^(14.9832))/(d^(14.9832) + 0.8265^(14.9832))) == 0},  0], {d, T}, Reals, 4]
```

> `{{d -> 0, T -> 13/5000}, {d -> 0, T -> 1}}`

The same result without any warning is produced with `Complexes` instead of `Reals`.

Comment: Its verification {-0.006`   d - 
    0.005999999999999999`   d   ProductLog[-90.53333333333333`  \
E^(-72.73766666666666` + 90.53333333333333`  d)] == 
   0, (1 - 0.0026/
       T)  (0.0885  (1 - 
         T)  (0.8265^(14.9832))/(d^(14.9832) + 0.8265^(14.9832)) - 
      0.978  (d^(14.9832))/(d^(14.9832) + 0.8265^(14.9832))) == 
   0} /. {d -> 0.742621, T -> -1.22352} produces `{False, False}`.

Comment: The values `{d -> 0.742621, T -> -1.22352} ` do not satisfy the original system (without rounding) as shown in my comment.